# How to get a DoubleClicked event from a reflex-dom listbox

Tags: haskell, reflex

The following code displays a reflex-dom dropdown element visually as a listbox and displays at the bottom always the last selected (clicked) line.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import           Reflex.Dom
import qualified Data.Text as T
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import           Data.Monoid((<>))
import           Data.Maybe (fromJust)

main :: IO ()
main = mainWidget $ el "div" $ do
  dd <- dropdown "2" (constDyn countries) $ def & attributes .~ constDyn ("size" =: "10")
  el "p" $ return ()
  let selItem = result <$> value dd 
  dynText selItem
  return ()

countries :: Map.Map T.Text T.Text
countries = Map.fromList [("1", "France"), ("2", "Switzerland"), ("3", "Germany"), ("4", "Italy"), ("5", "USA")]

result :: T.Text -> T.Text
result key = "You selected: " <> fromJust (Map.lookup key countries)
```

I want to change this code, so it displays at the bottom always the last **double clicked** line!

I tried several things

- use the *domEvent* function: This does not work, because *Dropdown* is not an instance of the *HasDomEvent* class.
- filter the event in the value *_dropdown_change* of the Dropdown record. But I didn't find any way to filter only DoubleClick events.
- use the newtype *EventSelector*. Again I don't see hwo I can use it.

**Question:** How can I get at the double click event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `domEvent` to get at the double click.

The following code uses `elAttr` to create a listbox like the one you created with dropdown.  The `domEvent` function is used to create double click `Event`'s for each of the listbox options which are then combined to get a `Dynamic` that represents the most recently double clicked option.

I left the dropbox code in place for comparison purposes.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import           Reflex.Dom
import qualified Data.Text as T
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import           Data.Monoid((<>))
import           Data.Maybe (fromJust)
import           Data.Traversable (forM)


-- a listbox that responds to double clicks
listbox :: MonadWidget t m =>    T.Text                -- default
                              -> Map.Map T.Text T.Text -- entries
                              -> Map.Map T.Text T.Text -- attributes
                              -> m (Dynamic t T.Text)  
listbox def entries attr = do
  optEv <- elAttr "select" attr $ 
             forM (Map.toList entries) $ \(i,c) -> do

               let sel = if i == def
                         then "selected" =: "selected"
                         else mempty 

               (e, _) <- elAttr' "option"  sel $ text c

               return (i <$ domEvent Dblclick e)

  holdDyn def $ leftmost optEv

main :: IO ()
main = mainWidget $ el "div" $ do
  -- original code (responds to single clicks)
  dd <- dropdown "2" (constDyn countries) $ def & attributes .~ constDyn ("size" =: "10")
  el "p" $ return ()
  let selItem = result <$> value dd
  dynText selItem

  el "p" $ return ()

  -- new code (responds to double clicks)
  lb <- listbox "3" countries ("size" =: "10")
  el "p" $ return ()
  let dblItem = result <$> lb
  dynText dblItem

  return ()

countries :: Map.Map T.Text T.Text
countries = Map.fromList [("1", "France"), ("2", "Switzerland"), ("3", "Germany"), ("4", "Italy"), ("5", "USA")]

result :: T.Text -> T.Text
result key = "You selected: " <> fromJust (Map.lookup key countries)
```

Comment: Many thanks! This is very clean, a good explanation and works perfectly. Unfortunately I have not yet enough points to upvote your answer...

Comment: It's not necessary to import `GHCJS.DOM.Events`. Everything can be done within Reflex.Dom: The function call to _wrapDomEvent_ can be deleted and the next line written as: `return (i <$ domEvent Dblclick e)`

Comment: Thanks!  Yes that's better of course.  I edited the answer accordingly.